# Popup exceptions in line items (SOLine)

Tags: acumatica

How to display popup exceptions instead of the one with a red dot on the row for the line items? I was able to have them in RowInserting for a little bit but after a series of code changes I get the red dot one instead. It even did not create a new row as I wanted but now it does. RowInserting event:

```
    protected virtual void SOLine_RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
    {
        var listMissingOEdesc = new List<int>();
        var select = Base.Transactions.Select();

        foreach (SOLine row in select)
        {
            var isOEDesc = IsOEDescEnabled(sender, row);
            var rowExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(row);
            if (isOEDesc == true)
                if (rowExt.UsrOedesc == null)
                    listMissingOEdesc.Add(row.SortOrder.Value);

        }

        if (listMissingOEdesc.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new PXException("Line items with sort order {0} do not have OE Desc filled out. Cannot add a new line.", string.Join(", ", listMissingOEdesc));
        }
        else
            Base.Actions.PressSave();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way, if any at all, to display popup exception and prevent the grid from inserting a new row. The way the framework is designed, PXGrid first inserts a new row on the webpage. After that PXGrid sends a callback to the application server either requesting default field values for the new row (if PXGrid's Mode has `InitNewRow="True"`) or sends all values captured from the webpage to the application server, so the new row can be inserted in the PXCache. Whenever an event handler, on the field or row level, gets invoked, the new row will still be visible to the user on the web page. Even if you invoke Ask method on the Transactions data view within one of the event handlers, the new row won't disappear from the webpage.

With all that said, the best and probably the only way to display popup exception and prevent the grid from inserting a new row is by replacing the standard **Add New Row** button on PXGrid with a custom action, which will first run the validation and display popup exception, if necessary. Otherwise, a new row will be inserted into PXGrid. It's also required to enable or disable the custom **NewSOTran** action based on the state of the standard PXGrid's **Insert** button.

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewSOTran.SetEnabled(Base.Transactions.AllowInsert);
    }

    public PXAction<SOOrder> NewSOTran;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField]
    protected void newSOTran()
    {
        var listMissingOEdesc = new List<SOLine>();
        var select = Base.Transactions.Select();

        foreach (SOLine row in select)
        {
            var isOEDesc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.TranDesc);
            if (isOEDesc == true)
                listMissingOEdesc.Add(row);
        }

        if (listMissingOEdesc.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new PXException("Cannot add a new line.");
        }

        var newTran = Base.Transactions.Insert();
        Base.Transactions.Cache.ActiveRow = newTran;
    }
}
```

In Aspx there will required 3 major chages:

1. **SyncPositionWithGraph** property set to ***True*** for PXGrid:

   ```
   <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" TabIndex="100" 
      SkinID="DetailsInTab" StatusField="Availability" SyncPosition="True" Height="473px" 
      SyncPositionWithGraph="True" >
   ```
2. the standard **AddNew** action must be replaced by a custom **NewSOTran** action:

   ```
   <ActionBar>
       <Actions>
           <AddNew ToolBarVisible ="False" />
       </Actions>
       <CustomItems>
           <px:PXToolBarButton CommandName="NewSOTran" CommandSourceID="ds" 
                               DisplayStyle="Image">
               <Images Normal="main@AddNew" />
               <ActionBar GroupIndex="0" Order="2" />
           </px:PXToolBarButton>
           ...
       </CustomItems>
   </ActionBar>
   ```
3. **AllowAddNew** property set to false in the **Mode** section of PXGrid to prevent the standart **Insert** button from execution when users use keyboard shortcuts or double-click on PXGrid:

   ```
   <Mode InitNewRow = "True" AllowFormEdit="True" AllowUpload="True" AllowDragRows="true" 
         AllowAddNew="false" />
   ```

To select new records’ first cell and switch it to the edit mode (unless the first cell is read-only), it's also required to subscribe to the **Initialize** and **ToolsButtonClick** client events of PXGrid:

```
<ClientEvents Initialize="initTransactionsGrid" 
              ToolsButtonClick="transactionsGriduttonClick" />
```

and define the following JavaScript functions:

```
var isInitEvents = false;
function initTransactionsGrid(a, b) {
    if (isInitEvents) return;

    isInitEvents = true;
    a.events.addEventHandler("afterRepaint", editNewSOTran);
}

function editNewSOTran() {
    if (lastActiveRowIndex != null) {
        var grid = px_alls["grid"];
        if (grid.activeRow) {
            var activeRowIndex = grid.rows.indexOf(grid.activeRow);
            if (activeRowIndex != lastActiveRowIndex) {
                grid.activeRow.activateCell(0, false);
                grid.beginEdit();
            }
        }
        lastActiveRowIndex = null;
    }
}

var lastActiveRowIndex;
function transactionsGriduttonClick(sender, args) {
    if (args.button && args.button.commandName == "NewSOTran") {
        if (sender.activeRow) 
            lastActiveRowIndex = sender.rows.indexOf(sender.activeRow);
        else
            lastActiveRowIndex = -1;
        return;
    }
    lastActiveRowIndex = null;
}
```

To package custom JavaScript code into customization, in Layout Editor you can drag and drop a **Java Script** element from the Add Controls tab and copy your entire JavaScript code into the **Script** property.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. Funny it works when you use "add stock item" button instead. I guess it behaves similarly to custom add button.

Comment: is there any way to set focus in the first field, as with regular add button?